# Find boundary of a set (interval), What to use?

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization, numerical-optimization

So directly I will State my problem:

Given $\epsilon >0$ and some function $f$, required to find $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 >0$ such that, for any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$  we have $$ |x_1|\leq \epsilon_1 \text{ and }    |x_2|\leq \epsilon_2  \implies |f(x_1,x_2) |\le \epsilon  $$

**How I describe the problem:** The idea is to find intervals (  or sets) in which 
the function $f$ on these two sets will not exceed a given  threshold.

**What I have tried:** I tried to transform this into an optimization problem. What stopped me is that  the boundary  restrictions (  $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$) are not constraints  they are the variables that we are searching for.

My knowledge in optimisation is modest (I took  2 courses in optimisation three years ago) so I am asking for some help. May be there will be another way to do such problems, can some one help me please.

Comment: Do you know what $f $ is? For example is it a continuous function at $0$?

Comment: @Any I am able to put some conditions on $f$, so it is possible to suppose $f$ continuous.

Comment: Maybe you could use continuity of $f$ at zero, and find each of the two bounds by considering the given function as function of one variable (consider the bahaviour as one of the $x_i $s is fixed.

Comment: @Any By fixing one variable, we will loose the possibility of having the same results when varying both variables.  May be I misunderstand you, so can you elaborate more please?